# Maven copy parents declared in the POMs

Tags: maven, android-maven-plugin

My final goal is to create a Maven repository in a certain directory containing **only** a certain set of artifacts and all their dependencies.

For this I use the following command:

```
mvn.bat dependency:copy-dependencies -f dependencies.pom
        -DoutputDirectory=localRepoDir -Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout=true
        -Dmdep.copyPom=true -Dmdep.addParentPoms=true
```

**dependencies.pom** being:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <description>Dependencies</description>
  <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
  <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dependency1</groupId>
      <artifactId>dep1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dependency2</groupId>
      <artifactId>dep2</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When doing this, I notice that parents declared in the dependencies' poms are not copied from the .m2 Local maven repository to the destination directory.

Perhaps I'm missing something and there's a better way to do this, since it's kind of a hack to use a pom file to declare the artifacts I want to copy (together with their dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `maven` was using version `2.8` as default for the [dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). When explicitly indicating it to use the latest version (`2.10`), it worked just fine.

The `addParentPoms` parameter was already introduced on `2.8` for [copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html), so I guess it must be a bug in the `2.8` release.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies
```